# How do you define POST parameters using inputs in the request body?

Tags: file, rest, post, upload, action

I am making a POST request to a RESTFUL api and the only way I can pass the parameters is if I add them into the URL used in the forms 'action' parameter.  As soon as I take those parameters and put them down into the form's body component the request no longer works.  My question is how do I use the inputs within the form to define the request parameters instead of the embedding the parameters into the action URL?

I do notice that when I submit the request the request body parameters show up, but the actual request fails saying that the parameters are not there.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form target="hiddenIframe" method="POST" action="/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process/5853?action=addDocument&name=test123&docType=file&parts=none&accept=application/json&override-content-type=text/plain" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="instanceId" value="5823" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="myTestQ1" />
  <input type="text" name="docType" value="file" />
  <input id="myFileName" type="file" name="data" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe" style="display: none;" />
```

As you can see the action in the form tag is very long and is not dynamic... I would like to only have "/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process/" there, but when I do the upload fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some Javascript. Add an onchange to all the mandatory input fields. And the change method you'll be calling can update your action url with the new data from the form field.

Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="instanceId" value="5823" onchange="updateInstanceID()" id="instanceid" />
action="/rest/bpm/wle/v1/process/5853?action=addDocument&name=test123&docType=file&parts=none&accept=application/json&override-content-type=text/plain"
```

Now, your Javascript should have that method.

```
function updateInstanceID() {
    var val = document.getElementById("instanceid").value;
    var form = document.forms[0]; // assuming only one form on the page.
    ....
}
```

Now you can access your form.action field and update it accordingly.